# 快 vs 快点, what's the point of "点" in this case?

Tags: word-choice

快 is one of the HSK level 2 vocabulary words which means "quick". Issue is this: I know online translators are unreliable but each translator I've used translates "快点去开门" as "Go and get the door" while completely missing the "quickly" aspect. When I instead type "快点去开门" the translators understand it to mean "Hurry up and get the door." (as it should).

So is this a problem with the online translators or is the "点" required? I know a few different ways "点" is used but I can't tell what its purpose in "快点" is. If the "点" is necessary to get the point across (no pun intended) why does every HSK vocabulary list I look up list "快" rather than "快点"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

点 (or 点儿 in Northern-speak) is short for 一点 (一点儿) / "one bit", so 快(一)点(儿) means "quick by a bit" = a bit more quickly (than the speed at the point of speaking).

I love the pun in your "What's the point of 点..."; one of the definitions of 点 is "point / dot" (as in decimal point; 5.3 = 五点三).

Comment: yea I noticed the pun at the time

Answer (score 0):

**一点** means a **dot** or **point** originally, also means **a bit** or **a little**. But, often, an extra **儿** is appended for the meaning **a bit**. That means, if you say **这一点** it usually means **this point/view**, **这一点儿** it means **so little** or **few**. But sometimes you don't need it, depending on the context. The tone of **一** is the fourth tone here. If you read **一** in the first tone, it means generally **one o'clock**. For example, **现在一点了** means **it is one o'clock**.

When translate it in Google, I got **hurry to open the door**, just [try it here](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E5%BF%AB%E7%82%B9%E5%8E%BB%E5%BC%80%E9%97%A8).